# Deploy Apache WebServer and Wordpress on different servers

Tags: wordpress, apache

Most tutorials have the Apache WebServer and WordPress installed on the same server. Is it possible to have the Apache WebServer and WordPress installed on different servers and route traffic from the Apache WebServer to the WordPress App server?

Comment: How do you plan to run Wordpress without some kind of a web server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can use a reverse proxy to achieve what you want. See link below

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/reverse_proxy.html

Comment: i dont understand what you mean here. how can you reverse prxoy a bare wordpress installation ?

Comment: There is no such thing as a bare wordpress installation. Wordpress has dependencies, for example you have to have PHP programming language installed or wordpress will not function as it is written in PHP. Wordpress will not function without a connection to a database, so you will have to install MySQL or similar to get wordpress to function.   There is no such thing as a bare wordpress installation.

Comment: i think you missed what i am asking here, you have answered that one can use a reverse proxy on a wordpress installation done on another remote machine. My question is what  you connect your reverse proxy to? Elaborate your answer, with respect to this particular question.

Comment: Read the link I provided in my original answer,  it explains what you do not understand.

Comment: you think i am commenting on your answer without having first hand experience on wordpress hosting and nginx/apache management ?. Don't get me wrong, but i intented to point that your answer is misleading, at least with refernce to this context. If you can say me how you host a worpdress website without a webserver, then you can prove me wrong.

Comment: this is an example of someone posting a leading comment, they are trying to get you to respond in a certain manor so that they can interject some pre prepared statement hahaha better luck next time but I saw you coming from a mile away